# Does the address of node and node's data is same in Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures

When we point a node with pointer, as pointer stores the address of next node in Linked Lists(say, the address of next node is 216) then does the data of next node have same address as of the pointer(i.e. next node's data is at address 216??)(here data is elements in Linked List)?

Comment: Depends. How does the structure look? Either way, don't use a pointer to a structure as a pointer to some other data, as that will break *strict aliasing*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a structure:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

and suppose we have some `struct Node x` where `x->next` points to the next node and is not currently a null pointer. Then `x->next` is the address of the next node. It is also the “same” address as the address of the first data in the next node, `&x->next->data`:

- It is the same in the sense it points to the same place in memory, because the starts starts at the same place the data in the structure starts.
- It is different because it has a different type. The type of `x->next` is `struct Node *`, while the type of `&x->next->data` is `int *`. This difference is meaningful because C treats different types differently even if they have the same “value.”

Note that the phrase “same address as of the pointer” is unclear because a pointer has two addresses: The address **of** the pointer itself is where the pointer is stored in memory. E.g., given some pointer `p`, `&p` is the address of the object named `p`. But the **value** of the pointer is the place it points to. In an expression, `p` is the value of `p`, so it is the address that `p` points to. I advise never using “address of the pointer” to refer to place the pointer points to.